# Android ViewPagerIndicator does not refresh

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

first of all I am using the ViewPagerIndicator from the following link to display the count of views inside of my view-pager: http://viewpagerindicator.com/

I used a CirclePageIndicator with just the usually code... my XML looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
    android:name="detailFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/pageIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:fillColor="@android:color/black"
        app:pageColor="@android:color/white"
        app:radius="6dp"
        app:strokeColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

My java code to set the adapter and the indicator is also nothing special and will be posted below (from my activity class)

```
  final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
  final DutyViewPager adapter = new DutyViewPager(this.getFragmentManager(), pkid, pager.getAdapter());
  pager.setAdapter(adapter);
  final CirclePageIndicator cIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) this.findViewById(R.id.pageIndicator);
  cIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
```

**Problem**: Lets say, we have a navigation with two elements linked to two different ViewPagerAdapter. The first element links to the adapter **A**, which displays a count of **2 fragments** and the second element links to the adapter **B**, which displays a count of **3 fragments**. After clicking at the first element my view will update with adapter **A**, loading the first fragment from the adapter and showing **2 circles** as adapter-count - so basicly, everything is as expected till now.
After clicking at the second element, my view is lodaing the adapter **B**, **but the view is still showing only 2 circles,** so I guess the indicator is not updating or something... the problem is fixed at the moment I swipe to the right side to display the next fragment in **adapter B**. (it shows 3 circles after swiping)

Just wondering if it´s just me or if someone else got this problem (and a solution) as well?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem before, after looking into the onDraw method in CirclePageIndicator.java, I found that it was caused by setting snap to true. After changing snap to false, everything looks good.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="StyledIndicators" parent="Theme.Light">
        <item name="vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomCirclePageIndicator</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomCirclePageIndicator">
        <item name="snap">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: thank you! finally someone with a solution that actually worked!

Answer (score 1):

A very late reply but you need to call notifyDataSetChanged() on your instance of ViewPagerIndicator.

Answer (score 1):

setCurrentItem(0) will work for you

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hacky, perhaps, but I couldn't get any of the other solutions to work, so after manually setting the page, I just called this on my page indicator:

```
titleIndicator.onPageScrolled(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0, 0);
```